# PHP: calling require_once in constructor function

Tags: php, constructor, require-once

`require_once` in constructor function, is not working I also tried include and require. `file_exists` function is working fine.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class App {

    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();
        //print_r($url);

        if(file_exists(__DIR__.'/../controllers/'. $url[0] . '.php')) {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        }

        require_once(__DIR__.'/../controllers/Home.php');
        echo $this->controller;

    }
}
```

Comment: What, specifically, is your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is it failing to load? What does the PHP error message say? Or is it loading but not running properly? In which case, what does the file that you're loading supposed to do? And what is going wrong?

Comment: @Simba , i got HTTP ERROR 500. 
you can check here - [Github][1].

[1]: https://github.com/iaditya/Progs/blob/master/codeCourse_MVC/myApp/app/core/App.php

Comment: If all you're getting is http 500, then you need to either check for the PHP error in your server logs, or set the PHP config to display errors in the browser. Once you see the actual PHP error message, it will almost certainly help you understand what's happening. A plain old http 500 error doesn't help at all.

Comment: Thanks @Simba. I did stupid things. error log helps me.